# Power supply for ATmega16

Tags: power-supply, avr, atmega

I am working with Atmega16 mc and it works on 5V. Also my project consists of IR sensors, LCD and few diodes. All of those works on 5V.
I am wondering how can i power this board.
I read somewhere  i can use USB or "Wall Wart" 5V power supply. Which do you think is better? 
And if that would even work? Also i know i need few capacitors 0.1uF there but not sure how many.

Yes, i am new to this field. It is my first project. I am working on smart parking, which means when IR detects car is parked, LED diode turns off and the display says how many parking spots are left.

There are 4 parking slots, but i am not sure yet how long wires would be. For now i am concentrated just on scheme and how to connect power supply with components. Do i need a voltage regulator for 5V supply? And do i need a bypass capasitors connected near?

Comment: there's no inherent "better" without telling us your measure for goodness. All this really reads as if you have no idea what you're doing – which is fine, we've all been new to this at some point – and that means you need to describe in far more breadth what it is that your device is designed to do, because you're not in any way describing your specifications for a power supply so far.

Comment: Any 5V supply will do, if it outputs 5V and provides more amps than what your board needs. How can we know which is better, you can. For designing with AVRs, read the hardware design application note.

Comment: Many small 5 volt "wall wart" power supplies use USB connectors, and the "USB chargers" for cell phones and tablets are really 5 volt power supplies.

Comment: Yes, i am new to this field. It is my first project. I am working on smart parking, which means when IT detects car is parked, LED diode turns off and the display says how many parking spots are left.

Comment: How many parking slots? The greater the number of slots, greater the area where the sensors will be installed. Maybe just one power 5V supply is not the best choice for this configuration, because low voltages (power and signal) don't travel so well through long runs of cable.

Comment: If there is a long distance, say more than 10 m, between the power source (like the mains electricity) and the point where you need the 5 V, then it would be a good idea to use a 12 V or 24 V DC adapter to the board and then use a 5 V buck regulator to convert the 12/24 V to 5 V. The reason for that is that there will then be less voltage drop on the long wires because they will be carrying less current for the same power (remember, V=IR and P=VI). But the long wires may not be your scenario - perhaps you could [edit] the question to say.

Comment: you can use an adaptor or If you have a programmer board it may have a 5v output, but it any cases using a 5v regulator like 7805 is necessary.